# How to convert PCRE regex to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, pcre

i have a regex :

```
/constructor.*?\nbegin\n(^(?:(?!inherited).)*$\n)+?end/igm;
```

( it searches delphi constructors without inherited keyword ). When i use it here : http://www.regextester.com/ it is working pretty nice

You can for example test it on string

```
constructor TAPISession.Create;
begin

  LastActivity:=Now;
  CS:= TCriticalSection.Create;
  APIObj:= TAdvancedServerObject.Create;
  CachedDomainsList:=TCachedDomainsList.Create;
  CachedAccountsList:= TCachedAccountsList.Create;
end;
```

But if i use it in php ( preg_match_all ) it does not work

```
preg_match_all('/constructor.*?\nbegin\n(^(?:(?!inherited).)*$\n)+?end;/im',$string,$matches);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you sure you've only got `\n` line breaks in there? maybe it's `\r\n` instead?

Comment: man i am so stupid :D thanks a lot , saved me second hour :D

Comment: Are you after the capture group 1? Access it via `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marc B, so the answer is simple just check also carriage return

```
preg_match_all('/constructor.*?\r?\nbegin\r?\n(^(?:(?!inherited).)*$\r?\n)+?end;/im',$string,$matches);
```